# JComboBox drop down show problem

Tags: java, applet, jcombobox

I am developing an applet, and use some panels, which according to some situations some panels are shown or hidden. in one panel I have a JComboBox which I fill them at runtime. my problem is when I show this panel, the JComboBox is filled, and enabled, but I cannot drop it down. I tested it on a simple applet, but it was correct, but I don't know why it does not show in my applet.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to compare the code in your simple example with the code in your real applet to see what is different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is NO difference.

Comment: It's a problem, not from my code, the UI does not work good. the drop down is like a disabled one.

Comment: If there is **NO** difference, use the 'simple' code as the end applet & stop bothering us.  Else look back to camickr's suggestion.

Comment: don't worry my brother, he should mention what does it mean the difference, I am sure my cods are equal, I used a java.awt.Panel with a javax.swing.JComboBox, that's it, I do not like to bother any one, some one who is not aware of the solution does not know the goal of the answer of the answerer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAG - don't mix Swing with AWT.

Comment: +1 Also consider these [guidelines](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/).